# Is it possible to merge UI Controls on MS Coded UI Tests?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

**Edit: Since my question was too long, and touched a lot of different points, I decided to brake it down into smaller and more specific questions.**

I am using Coded UI tests to run automated, however I realized UIMap generates the exact same element over and over again when I create different tests on the some page. Is it possible to merge this repeated elements? Please see screenshot below:

[image]

**Answer:**

stoj provided the best answer by suggesting http://uimaptoolbox.codeplex.com/ .It's a great tool to clean up those nasty repeated elements.

Comment: I haven't done a lot of web automation, have you tried using getparent/getchildren to navigate the dom?

Comment: GetParent and GetChildren returns UI Test Control, so it navigates the  elements displayed in the .uimap file.

Comment: I haven;t actually tested it but I am pretty sure GetParent/Child use the MSAA/UIAutomation tree and not the UIMap. If they used the UIMap how would GetParent react to a control created outside of the UIMap without a parent would they return the desktop?

Comment: You'r right. Using GetParent() gives me the DOM parent of the matched UI Control element. But somehow on my previously written tests I got always "null" when I used GetParent(). I created a new Test solution and now GetParent returns what's expected. Thanks stoj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an easy method for modifying properties on a large number of recorded controls at the same time. If the tests will run fine without the innertext property you could open the the UIMap.uitest file in your favorite text editor and delete them relatively quickly. Not an ideal solution but faster than doing the same thing in the test editor. You do of course want to keep a backup of the uitest file.

If the values have to change things get alot more complicated you could create a UIMap for each language and manually edit the xml file with the appropriate language.

I don't think there is any way to get rid of duplicated controls.There is a UIMap toolbox but I'm not sure it will actually remove duplicate controls. http://uimaptoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply stoj. Unfortunately I realized that removing all "inner text" matches is not enough. I would like to be able to navigate the DOM tree (which I don't know if it's possible). I took a look at that UI Map toolbox and it's perfect for my 2nd question. That tool is just missing the possibility of editing element properties.

Comment: @John Louros: For simple edits, a plain text editor is enough and for simple element manipulations, MS XML Notepad is the best tool.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Using Coded UI Test Builder, you can navigate in the UI hierarchy. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/01/13/coded-ui-test-tip-of-the-day-2-use-the-navigation-dial-to-move-around-in-the-ui-tree.aspx

Q2: UIMap toolbox is your best bet for merging the duplicate controls. We are aware of this issue and investigating to make a product fix.

Q3: We had made some fixes to handle the dynamic ids in SharePoint controls. Can you try with Visual Studio 2010 SP1? If you are using SP1, please let me know a specific scenario which fails for you. I can invetsigate further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mathew, I am currently working on another task, so when I wrap up everything I will be back on the testing solution. In a couple of days I may have a more detailed question, if not I will mark this question as answered. Thanks again.

Comment: Q1: Is true when doing Assertions. How do I do it while recording new tests?  Q3: I recorded a test that simply goes access SharePoint site settings. When I recorded the "site actions" link had zz9_siteactions id, when I ran it it had zz10_siteactions id. The test did not fail, but the test failed to access site settings page.

Comment: Regarding Q3, I tried again today and it worked. However, this doesn't solve my problem of supporting multiple languages with the same tests.